# Problem loading shapefiles, with different extents, in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, shapefile

I am trying to load 4 shapefiles for sectors in Eastern DRC. 3 will load, but the 4th will not. If I load the 4th first the others do not load?

I've read through, and followed, the other suggestions for similar problems and discovered that while each shapefile says it has the same CRS, the metadata the extents are different.

Walungu: `xMin,yMin 3151087.18,-331737.78 : xMax,yMax 3232786.69,-275904.03`

Mwenga: `xMin,yMin 27.697,-3.99776 : xMax,yMax 28.8922,-2.77678`

Walunugu is the shapefile that will only load by itself.

Both say that the selected CRS is `EPSG:4326, WGS84`.

I have tried `save as` for each layer and then reload them to see if that would change their extents, with no luck.

Is there any other way I change the extent? Is that even my problem?

Enable on the fly transformation is also selected.

Comment: Is there a `.prj` file associated to each shapefile in the same filepath?

Comment: Yes there is, this is what it shows in the texteditor:

Comment: sorry hit enter, GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",DATUM["D_WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137.0,298.257223563]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]]

Comment: Which is the CRS you want to use for displaying them? A geographic or a projected CRS?

Comment: I want to use  EPSG:4326, WGS84, but only because the other 3 shapefiles are displaying correctly using that CRS.

Comment: Is it possible sharing the `Walungu` and `Mwenga` shapefiles here? Maybe using a link from an external uploading service.

Comment: of course! here are both files here: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0BzWHhWichSXGNVozaldaTTBBSkU?usp=sharing

Comment: Thanks, I'll give a look. Should the layers contiguous?

Comment: much appreciated! yes they should be contiguous.

Comment: Mwenga's extents are in decimal degrees, so it probably is EPSG:4326. As for Walungu, I'm not sure what CRS this is, but it looks like a projected CRS and not a geographic one like EPSG:4326. Keep in mind that the CRS of a shapefile can be wrongly set, i.e., the prj says EPSG:4326 but the coordinates are in a different CRS. This means that QGIS is reading WGS84 but it has no way of interpreting the coordinate values since they are out of range.

Comment: Aha. okay that makes sense thank you. so without knowing what the projected CRS is for Walungu is there anyway to project both shapefiles in the CRS?

Comment: A really tricky task! Do you know a way to show how they should be both located? The best I have by now is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMcRL.png), but a distance of 100 km should be too much (I'm going blind without any reference about the crs)

Comment: oh wow that is amazing! I actually have several other shapefiles and the Walunugu one fills it in. I can upload those to the same shared file, but also don't want you to do all the work for me. How were you able to put it with a distance of 100km?

Comment: @SarahDRC if you know it surely fits inside them, please share these shapefiles: I think it will be the unique way to understand if I am wrong

Comment: The pcs coordinates don't match anything in the EPSG registry for DRC. The negative Y values imply a latitude of origin at the equator. The large X values mean that either there's a false easting value (possibly of 3 million) or that the data's well to the east of the central meridian. Unfortunately various UTM zones don't work.

Comment: Shucks, looks like I need to find another version of this shapefile, but thank you to everyone for the help!

Comment: @SarahDRC I just tried to compare the new shapefiles, but I think that Walunugu should need to be below the new shapefiles you attached, but this doesn't happen (it is still 100 far as in the image I previously attached). However, even trying to manually move the shapefile, I noted that its boundaries don't perfectly match the contigouos shapefiles, so probably the best would be to find another source... I'm sorry!

Comment: @SarahDRC - Where originally did you get these shapefiles from? Could you provide a link if it was from an online source?